# ending prepared statement queries (stmt->close)

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

currently i'm using mysql (stmt) queries as:
connecting from the main php file, then for each query im doing these:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

and nothing after with the stmt/mysql.

now i saw that i need to use these commands, and then:

```
$stmt->close()
$conn->close()
```

for the ending, but when exactly do i have to use them?
correct me if im wrong but, do i need to use the `$stmt->close();` after every query, and the `$conn->close()` at the bottom of each page? or after any query aswell?
how exactly do i use them, and why tho? how its affecting my website/what will happen if i wont use them?

Comment: You don't have to use them if the script will end soon, since everything is closed when the script exits.

Comment: More often than not a prepared statement is reused since it has the benefit of being cachable and avoiding parser overhead in the same session. So usually you won't close a statement after _every_ query. Additionally most php requests only last a fraction of a second. So people rarely need to close a db connection mid-stream. This is why the rule of thumb is: "don't bother closing resources, unless you know why, php will close them for you by default"

Comment: You only need to use them if the script keeps running for a while after using the database.